# How can I specify VM options in JNLP-based applet?

Tags: java, applet, jnlp

I need to specify system properties, i.e. smth like this "-Dx=1 -Dy=2" and pass it to the applet. Also - I launch it through JNLP.

Tried the following:

```xml
<j2se version="1.7+"  java_arguments="-Dx=1 -Dy=2" java-vm-args="-Dx=1 -Dy=2"/>
```

Also:

```html
<applet-desc main-class="my.AppletLauncher"
             name="Demo Applet"
             width="1000"
             height="1000">
    <param name="java-vm-args" value="-Dx=1 -Dy=2"/>
    <param name="java_arguments" value="-Dx=1 -Dy=2"/>
```

Nothing helps.

Comment: *"specify system properties, i.e. smth like.."*  No, I'm going to stop you there.  When it comes to system properties, some exist, some don't.  Further, while some can be set by a sand-boxed app., others require trust.  Some properties have separate, specific attributes to set them in JNLP.  So be specific.  What properties are you trying to set?

Comment: I mean exactly arbitrary properties. They are not something specific for Java. They are just my properties, specific for that applet only.

Comment: Then they are ***not**C System properties and should not be defined that way.  As mentioned by @etalbo, add them as properties in the JNLP file, and they should be retrievable in the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with *property* tag:

```xml
<resources>
    <j2se version="1.7+"/>
    <property name="x" value="1"/>
    <property name="y" value="2"/>
</resources>
```

Also read this https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8023821 about setting properties using JNLP.

Hope it helps.